# How to display a configurable product associated simple products data

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product, simple-product

I need to display attributes (additional information) of each simple product associated with the configurable product in Magento 1.9.

Comment: I tried to use Simple Configurable Product extension but I got this error in magento connect : CONNECT ERROR: Failed to open file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/downloader/.cache/community/OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts-0.7.4/app/code/community/OrganicInternet/SimpleConfigurableProducts/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurabl   .    Also this extension is not compatible with magento 1.9

Answer (score 2):

This extension fites your needs: [Better Configurable Products](http://de.nr-apps.com/store/bcp-better-configurable-products.html)

But be aware that it changes substantially how configurable products work internally, so there are some rewrites of important core classes. Though the overall quality is way above the "Simple Configurable Products" extension.

Also you should not expect it to work out of the box. This is not a "one click install and forget" extension, it should be installed and configured by a developer.

Comment: thanks for your help? but is there any free one.